# Eclipse plug-in - Finding source parts location

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am writing an Eclipse plug-in that should modify the source code in the Java editor.
How can I figure the location of the source section like

- class declaration
- imports
- class fields
- methods

and so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to understand how the [JDT](http://www.eclipse.org/jdt/index.php) works in Eclipse.

You could write something like this in a plugin:

```
IProject project = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot()
    .getProject(PROJECT_NAME);
IJavaProject javaProject = JavaCore.create(project);
IType type = project.findType(TYPE_NAME);
ICompilationUnit icu = type.getCompilationUnit();
```

Read [Manipulating Java code](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/guide/jdt_api_manip.htm) to see what you can do with `ICompilationUnit`.

If you want more options, you can generate an AST of your `ICompilationUnit`, using for example:

```
CompilationUnit parse(ICompilationUnit unit)
{
    ASTParser parser = ASTParser.newParser(AST.JLS3);
    parser.setKind(ASTParser.K_COMPILATION_UNIT);
    parser.setSource(unit);
    parser.setResolveBindings(true);
    return (CompilationUnit) parser.createAST(null);
}
```

Note that setting `resolveBindings` to `true` is expensive, so only do it when needed. `CompilationUnit` is the root of your AST, which you can visit using an [ASTVisitor](http://help.eclipse.org/help32/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jdt/core/dom/ASTVisitor.html). Agains see the [previous](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/guide/jdt_api_manip.htm) document to see what you can do with ASTs.

Read the documentation online, check the API of the types involved, and try to find the source code of some example plugins.

Answer (score 1):

You want to modify [Abstract Syntax Tree](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-JavaCodeManipulation_AST/index.html) (AST).